# Can I reduce the size of J2ME jar that is written with LWUIT?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, lwuit

I write J2ME application with LWUIT. After I finished my application, jar size is 0.99Mb. That is terrible size and that cannot debug with NetBean IDE 6.9 emulator. Only one touch emulator in NetBean IDE 6.9 can run it and other are not sufficient space to install. But I test my application with Nokia 5530 and Nokia N85, that is good for use. But other lowest JVM mobile phone doesn't run that size. How can I reduce the size of jar? LWUIT jar size (need to add jar for my application) is 700kb...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [obfuscating](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/28989) for reducing the `jar` file size. Set the obfuscating level to `High` in your netbeans project. And then clean and build the project. Now see the `jar` file size. It will be reduce.

Answer (score -1):

Obfuscation may be the way but I'm sure you won't use all features of LWUIT then removing unused classes by [jarOpt](http://www.fightingquaker.com/jaropt/) should help. And generally repack all jars and classes into one JAR with highest compression level.

Comment: Obfuscation automatically removes unused classes and methods making jarOpt redundant.

Comment: But obfuscating makes debugging very hard. OP wants to debug it as well.

Comment: You don't obfuscate when debugging, since you don't have reflection anyway you can't use it for logs or stack traces in production. Jar size only matters in production not during debugging.

Comment: But OP said he/she has problems with loading it in emulator for debugging. And what about On Device Debugging?

Comment: I missed that one. The answer is simple though: don't use Java SDK 3.0. Its an awful, slow simulator that times out too quickly and has too many bugs (wait for 3.1 it should be better). In the meantime we all use Sprint WTK 3.3.x which is much faster and easier to use. Anyway, you are better off building LWUIT from source when debugging so you can step into LWUIT which makes a huge difference.

Comment: @bharath please do you think you could help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730176/j2me-how-to-parse-a-byte-array-into-xml-and-then-read-and-display-specific-data