# j2me: How to parse a byte array into xml and then read and display specific data from that XML

Tags: xml, java-me, kxml2, kxml

I'm consuming a ASP.NET Web API method that returns data in xml format.
Everything was fine until I had to parse the byte array I got ,resulting from the openInputStream. 
Everyone says use this or that library,but unfortunately there isn't much info and the only decent example I found was from a deprecated library called KXML ,in which the author read a physical document (obviously not my case).
Personally I wanted to use KXML2, but I this point I'm desperate and open to the very first solution that lets me read XML in the easiest possible way.

Here's is the code I use to consume the Web API method :

```
HttpConnection connection = null;
InputStream is = null;

final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

byte[] response = null;

try {
    connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://myminimarket/api/customers/GetCustomers", Connector.READ);
    connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);

    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1");

    if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        is = connection.openInputStream();

        if (is != null) {
            int ch = -1;

            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                bos.write(ch);
            }

            response = bos.toByteArray();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (bos != null) {
            bos.close();            
        }

        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
            is = null;
        }

        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
            connection = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here's is a sample of XML result I got from the method  **GetCustomers**:

```
<ArrayOfCustomer xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WSWebAPI.Helpers">
<Customer>
<codigoCli>30</codigoCli>
<direccion>MCDO. SAN MARTIN PSTO. Nº 06</direccion>
<nroID>26626315</nroID>
<nroTelef>365548</nroTelef>
<razonSocial>ABANTO CASTAÑEDA, PAULA</razonSocial>
<tipoPersona>N</tipoPersona>
</Customer>
<codigoCli>61</codigoCli>
<direccion>
JR. SANTA TERESA DE JUORNET MZA. L. LOTE 11 (FRENTE AL QUINDE-COSTADO DE FARMACIA)
</direccion>
<nroID>10414741067</nroID>
<nroTelef/>
<razonSocial>ACUÑA SIFUENTES, ILZE SOLEDAD</razonSocial>
<tipoPersona>N</tipoPersona>
</Customer>
<Customer>
<codigoCli>69</codigoCli>
<direccion>JR. JOSE GALVEZ Nº 478</direccion>
<nroID>15586005</nroID>
<nroTelef/>
<razonSocial>AEDO YANQUI, MARGARITA</razonSocial>
<tipoPersona>N</tipoPersona>
</Customer>
<Customer>
<codigoCli>115</codigoCli>
<direccion>JR. AMALIA PUGA Nº 1008 TELEF. 367878</direccion>
<nroID>10266028356</nroID>
<nroTelef/>
<razonSocial>ALARCON ZEGARRA, EDULFO</razonSocial>
<tipoPersona>N</tipoPersona>
</Customer>
```

With these details, I would like to find a way to display something like this:

> Customer # 1:
>
> codigoCli: 30
>
> direccion : MCDO. SAN MARTIN PSTO. Nº 06
>
> nroID : 26626315
>
> nroTelef: 365548
>
> razonSocial: ABANTO CASTAÑEDA, PAULA
>
> tipoPersona: N
>
> ---
>
> Customer # 2:
>
> .....

I really hope you can understand my situation, being a .net developer, it is really frustrating not finding much info on topic like this one.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you take a look on this answer? Here I've explained how to parse an XML fron Java2ME [Parsing XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175745/xml-parsing-not-working-on-android-build-of-lwuit-app)

Comment: Thanks. It looks great and it might be what I'm looking for. The problem is that for some reason the execution stops at this point : `XMLParser myParser = new XMLParser();`

Comment: Does it show any exception??

Comment: Yes now that you mention it. This is what I get from the output window "Uncaught exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/lwuit/xml/XMLParser
 - MIDkxml.lookUp(MIDkxml.java:112)
 - MIDkxml.run(MIDkxml.java:65)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)"

Comment: I'm really interested in using lwuit, because we don't need to create classes to read XML files

Comment: It's a very strange exception, did you have the last LWUIT version??

Answer (score 2):

You can use setInput(new ByteArrayInputStream(response), null /*null for autodetection, or specify proper encoding id string*/) method to parse the xml response. Or what is the problem with kxml2 exactly?

Comment: I found this tutorial http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/XML_Parser_in_Java_ME , but the XML is read from an existing file

Comment: @alex another thing I don't understand in that tutorial, being a completely newbie in the java world, is the "Utility" thing

Comment: Here is a sample code that uses kxml2 to parse your XML, it is too big for comment, so here is a link: [Kxml2Demo.java](http://to.neznam.sweb.cz/Kxml2Demo.java). Method `GetCustomer` reads content from a [file](http://to.neznam.sweb.cz/spanishWS.xml) and returns byte array to show how to use it as the input for the parser.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's much more than what I expected to get. But tell me, is it for a MIDLET?? I ask because from the little I know the program should follow an structure like having an startApp() method for example.

Comment: Sure you can use the parsing code code in a midlet. There is `main(string[])` method in the example just so I could test it on Windows command line :). I use KXML2 to parse XML like this in my j2me application (midlet). I believe the example builds against and runs with just CLDC-1.1 and kxml2.